# Using a loop to modify several columns of data in R based on other columns

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through several columns of data and update the rows in one column based on the rows in another.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble("A" = c(rnorm(10)), "B" = c (rnorm(10)), "AA" = c(rnorm(10)), "BB" = c(rnorm(10)))

df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     A       B     AA     BB
 <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.278  -1.21   -0.892 -1.07 
 2 -3.39   -0.0315  0.418  0.514
 3 -2.37   -0.374   0.504 -1.14 
 4 -0.642   0.590   1.24  -0.186
 5  1.48   -0.888  -0.610 -0.454
 6 -2.06    1.43   -0.197 -1.19 
 7  0.314   0.628  -1.36  -1.73 
 8 -0.122  -0.480   1.62   2.47 
 9 -0.0693  1.20   -0.498 -0.858
10  0.751  -0.389  -0.340  0.743
```

I want to set column A to NA is column AA is < 0.  The same for column B and BB, etc. etc.

I have an ifelse statement that works for one column at a time, but I need to put it into a loop or a map() function in purrr to loop across all the columns in succession. But every I try to put it into a for loop or use map_dbl(), I get errors.  Here is my working ifelse statement.

```
df <- mutate(df, A = ifelse(AA < 0, NA, A))
```

This is basically how I tried to do the loop:

This is basically how I tried to do it.  I'm new to R, so I may be completely off.

```
cleaning <- function(df,x,y,z) {df <- mutate(df, df$x == ifelse(df$y < 2, NA, df$z)) 
for (i in seq_along(x)) {df[i] <-cleaning[[i]]}
}

cleaning(df,A:B,AA:BB,A:B)
```

Here is a dput of the first 10 rows of my actual data.  The columns AF3:AF4 need to be updated based on CQ_AF3:CQ_AF4 having a value of < 2.

```
structure(list(ID = c(74L, 11L, 66L, 125L, 89L, 25L, 57L, 43L, 
114L, 47L), COUNTER = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), INTERPOLATED = c(4518.461428, 4573.333222, 4604.102452, 4655.384502, 
4570.256298, 4473.846044, 4610.256298, 4585.128093, 4721.538346, 
4653.84604), AF3 = c(3624.615296, 4025.640927, 4034.871696, 4004.615287, 
3971.281954, 3868.717854, 3968.205031, 4005.128107, 3898.974264, 
4058.461439), F7 = c(4345.128099, 4644.615271, 4665.128091, 4525.640915, 
4571.281939, 4804.615267, 4479.48707, 4614.358862, 4482.563993, 
4708.205013), F3 = c(3757.948626, 3978.974262, 4057.435798, 4118.974258, 
4061.538362, 3591.794784, 4060.512721, 4019.999902, 4203.589641, 
4068.717849), FC5 = c(4107.179387, 4126.153745, 4058.97426, 4085.640926, 
4098.461438, 4245.128101, 4094.358874, 4133.333232, 3742.051191, 
4152.307591), T7 = c(4316.410151, 4824.102446, 4765.128089, 4783.076806, 
4685.640911, 4422.051174, 4742.051166, 4710.769116, 4850.256292, 
4734.358859), P7 = c(4747.179371, 4458.97425, 4423.589635, 4497.948608, 
4578.974247, 4752.307576, 4418.46143, 4599.999888, 4713.333218, 
4579.487068), O1 = c(3947.179391, 3908.205033, 3966.66657, 4042.051183, 
4008.20503, 4006.153748, 3972.820416, 3984.615287, 4167.692206, 
3996.410159), O2 = c(4077.435798, 4171.281949, 4094.358874, 4147.179386, 
4121.538361, 4138.461437, 4137.948617, 4151.79477, 4134.358873, 
4118.974258), P8 = c(3606.666578, 3820.512727, 3874.35888, 4060.512721, 
3775.897344, 3631.794783, 3959.999903, 3896.410161, 3858.974265, 
3922.051186), T8 = c(4146.666565, 4330.256304, 4353.333227, 4415.384507, 
4338.461432, 3941.538365, 4432.307584, 4382.051175, 4587.692196, 
4419.999892), FC6 = c(4418.974251, 4632.8204, 4692.307578, 4634.871682, 
4568.717837, 4684.61527, 4363.589637, 4615.897323, 4654.358861, 
4631.794759), F4 = c(3808.205035, 4205.640923, 4373.846047, 4414.871687, 
4293.846049, 3727.692217, 4151.79477, 4218.461435, 4284.61528, 
4341.538355), F8 = c(4282.051177, 4243.076819, 4239.999896, 4437.435789, 
4340.512714, 3809.743497, 4276.922972, 4269.743485, 4536.922966, 
4360.512714), AF4 = c(487L, 484L, 513L, 444L, 444L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
482L, 0L), RAW_CQ = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    CQ_AF3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_F7 = c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_F3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_FC5 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_T7 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_P7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), CQ_O1 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_O2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CQ_P8 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_T8 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_FC6 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_F4 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), CQ_F8 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_AF4 = c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_CMS = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CQ_DRL = c(1768L, 1770L, 1767L, 
    1768L, 1768L, 1768L, 1768L, 1771L, 1767L, 1770L), GYROX = c(1515L, 
    1517L, 1511L, 1512L, 1516L, 1514L, 1514L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L
    ), `GYROY MARKER` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi @SueT, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you post the code of the for-loop that you tried to implement? Maybe we can work from there.

Comment: I edited my original post to add it.

Comment: Does your data frame have more than 4 columns? Is there a pattern in the columns that you want to check to determine whether or not to update another column, for example C is mutated if CC is negative, D is mutated if DD is negative, etc?

Comment: Yes, I have about 40 columns. 20 that need checked and 20 corresponding columns that need updated exactly in the pattern you described.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? This `df` created with `set.seed(123)`:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
        A      B      AA      BB
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  1.26   1.66  -0.675   0.183 
 2  1.52  -1.63  -1.16   -0.0934
 3  0.346  0.890  2.02    0.368 
 4  0.723 -0.532 -2.37   -0.580 
 5 -0.434  0.158  2.23    0.553 
 6  1.57   0.385  0.511   1.84  
 7 -0.516  1.25  -0.765  -2.05  
 8  0.561  0.313  0.0828 -0.214 
 9 -0.717 -1.46  -0.408  -0.166 
10 -1.84  -0.267 -0.414  -1.05
```

Then the modified df:

```
> df %>% mutate_at(vars(A), funs(ifelse(AA < 0, NA, .))) %>% 
         mutate_at(vars(B), funs(ifelse(BB < 0, NA, .)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
         A       B     AA      BB
     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  NA       1.22  -1.07   0.426 
 2  NA      NA     -0.218 -0.295 
 3  NA       0.401 -1.03   0.895 
 4  NA       0.111 -0.729  0.878 
 5  NA      -0.556 -0.625  0.822 
 6  NA       1.79  -1.69   0.689 
 7   0.461   0.498  0.838  0.554 
 8  -1.27   NA      0.153 -0.0619
 9  NA      NA     -1.14  -0.306 
10  -0.446  NA      1.25  -0.380
```

If you need to save the modified `df`, just put `newname <-` at the front of this command.

Comment: That works, but my actual data set has about 40 columns to run through, so I either need a for loop or purrr::map() to do it efficiently and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post via `dput` a complete minimal subset of your data... hard to figure out an appropriate solution with missing information. Thanks :)

Comment: I added it to the original post along with what needs done.

Answer (score 0):

Simple for-loop solution without loading external libraries:

```
> df
             A           B          AA           BB
1  -1.13879933 -0.05219939  1.40599762  0.277708500
2  -1.60341369 -1.23928624  0.25177871  0.009469529
3           NA  0.44474461 -0.68301589  1.914665838
4           NA          NA -0.49642122 -0.555400536
5  -2.83194181          NA  0.09429098 -0.324189223
6   1.06254068          NA  0.84104522 -1.121906866
7   0.04871273          NA  1.13978470 -1.527878009
8           NA          NA -1.29621577 -0.818883608
9   0.43346025          NA  0.45678599 -0.673519674
10 -0.08255017          NA  0.83648472 -1.851880253
```

#### Code

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(df))(
        if(paste0(colnames(df[i]), colnames(df[i])) == colnames(df[j]))(
            for(k in 1:nrow(df))(
                if(df[k, j] < 0)(
                    df[k, i] <- NA
                )
            )    
        )
    )    
}
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(1701)
df <- data.frame("A" = c(rnorm(10)), "B" = c (rnorm(10)),
                 "AA" = c(rnorm(10)), "BB" = c(rnorm(10)))
```

======================================================

#### Bonus: Commented code for your real data

```
# Iterate through all columns for base i and match j
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(df))(
        # Check if name of base + prefix is the same as match
        if(paste0("CQ_", colnames(df[i])) == colnames(df[j]))(
            # Iterate through rows
            for(k in 1:nrow(df))(
                # Check value in match row
                if(df[k, j] < 2)(
                    # Update value in same row of base
                    df[k, i] <- NA
                ) 
            )    
        )
    )    
}
```

This works with both `tibbles` and `data.frames`. If you have `NA` data you should also use `!is.na()` or something else to exclude those cases, otherwise the value check will complain.